# Python project explanation

Tags: python, linux

this might be the "again-python-project" one topic, but I am interested how to make a project, for example a simple game, which will have an installer so the user can just double clcik and install a working game in some dir (specified later). I was looking for setup.py, distutils, easy_install and pip, but mu projects keep saying that installing in /home/user/install_dir is not in env.variable PYTHONPATH, which I changed in python sys.path... I am just asking how I build my project, so it is:

1. ordered in dirs
2. user installable
3. includes all needed libs ( which I think is the only working option from my setup.py-es)
4. user uninstallable
   For more info - I was reading Zed Shaw`s Learn Python The Hard Way, and on his chapter for building a project skeleton, none of his steps were working, besides the nosetests, I tested it with both py2 and py3.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you need a way to distribute a Python project and all it's dependencies. 
Did you try [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) already. It allows you to "freeze" your (and all needed) Python modules into one executable. It also provides mechanisms to set up the environment as needed.

Comment: Yes, partially. I need exactly that, but I want to make it by hand and to understand the dirs and locations of all files, and what exactly they refer to "module".

Comment: PyInstaller is not [despite the name]... an installer. It just generate huge binaries.

Answer (score 0):

**Under GNU/Linux, the standard way to install software is through repositories**. This is how you get automatic updates and dependency installation and it is the way you should probably go.

Sometimes you will find "binary packages" like `mypackage.deb` or `mypackage.rpm` that will be installed by double clicking on them. However, this packages are typically the same thing that you would put in a repository, so it is about the same difficulty to prepare them but you will lose the goodies that come with repositories.

Packaging under GNU/Linux is closer to an art than to a science, as each of the major distros seem to take pride in developing their own package manager, and all of them differ greatly from each other. If you are under ubuntu, and your software will be free (as in "free speech"), you could take advantage of the [extensive documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Python) and of their [freely available PPA's](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA) [sort of "mini-repositories"].

Python - as you already discovered - offers an alternative "package manager" based on PyPI (The Python Package Index), but using this on *nix systems is typically discouraged, as packages installed via PyPI do not know about those already present in your system via the main package manager, so you will probably end up having duplicate packages or different versions of the same packages.

Even worse from a design perspective is [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/), which creates large executables (later compressed) including *everything* your software will need to run. Despite its name, PyInstaller is not an installer. It just creates huge executables. From [their FAQ](http://www.pyinstaller.org/wiki/FAQ):

> Despite its name (which has more to do with its historical roots), PyInstaller is used to transform a Python program into a native executable form which does not require existing Python installations to run. Building an installer program is totally outside the scope of PyInstaller.

Now, as for your requirements:

> ordered in dirs

All package managers will do this automatically. The target directories are dependent on the target system though (i.e.: you never hard-code the directory location of your source files, is the system that decides where to store them).

PyInstaller won't do anything of sort, of course.

> user installable

On GNU/Linux systems this cannot be done unless the user has root privileges [regardless of the package being pulled from a repository or being a binary file, as the blocking part is the user not having write permission to system-wide directories]. The closest you can do is for the user to create a directory tree in his home folder (for example under `~/.local` and put your source files there. This works quite well if the system already has the needed dependencies, but if your source say depends from a C lib that is not installed, you are out of luck.

> includes all needed libs ( which I think is the only working option from my setup.py-es)

This is one of the main features of a package manager (deb, rpm, yum...). PyPI will be able to pull the *python* dependencies for your program, but it won't be able to pull the binary ones [so if your dependency is for example a binding for a C library, you will get the binding, but you have to get elsewhere the C library].

**The bottom line is: packaging is hard, and there is no easy way around it.**

Comment: Thank you, mac, even though it was kinda discouraging, since C building was easier compared to pythons... Looks like pyinstaller is the alternate I`d stick while I am a python noob since it is closing me to C output files.

Comment: This is the correct answer for GNU/Linux systems. As some extra clarification, typically the modules that you write get installed somewhere in your $PYTHONPATH (ie /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages on my system), while a script for launching the program, which has its executable bit set (`chmod +x scriptname` on the commandline) and with `#! /usr/bin/python` as its first line, is installed in the system executable path (typically `/usr/bin`). Installing via a Linux repo or PyPI essentially automates this process.